# Node's Version of httpresponse.isclientconnected?

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js

So I'm coming from a background of .net and now I'm getting into Nodejs.

So one thing keeps happening in my latest project (first real node project).  I get "Socket Hang Up".  What is that?

The page will also just spin and spin returning nothing.  So I was wondering if there was a Node equivalent for `HttpResponse.isClientConnected`?

Comment: Quite often a 'socket hang up' is when the response has closed the connection unexpectedly, without ending the response. For example, is the page expecting a request body that isn't being sent that then causes the socket to time out.

What context are you seeing this error in?

Comment: Well it's a single page site.  So I load the page up, all images/css/js loads. The page just site there while I look at other stuff.  Then in the Node console I get the `socket hang up`